# Python save 8 bit integers to file

Tags: python, binary-data

I have list with 8 bit numbers like [255, 8, 16, 254 ...] count of these files about 8000. 
I have question about saving these numbers, when i save it, it must be 8000 byte, am I false ?
But I have about 20kb. How can I save this numbers as 8 bit when I read it I want to read as byte.

```
file = open(name,"wb")
for el in data:
    file.write(bytes(el))
```

where is my mistake ? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends heavily on what Python version you are using.

If it is Python 3, you are calling `bytes()` incorrectly; by giving it an integer, you are asking for a `bytes()` object *of that size*:

```
>>> bytes(10)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

That's 10 null bytes, not one byte with the value 0x10.

Pass in a sequence instead:

```
>>> bytes([10])
b'\n'
```

In fact, you don't need your loop at all; if `data` is all integers, you can create your `bytes` object in one go and write that:

```
with open(name,"wb") as f:
    file.write(bytes(data))
```

If this is Python 2, you should not be using `bytes()` at all, it's just an alias for `str()`:

```
>>> bytes(10)
'10'
```

That's the characters `1` and `0` (ASCII codepoints 49 and 48), not a byte with value 0x10.

You *can* use `bytearray()` the same way you could use `bytes()` (and `bytearray()`) in Python 3; create *one* such object from `data` and write that:

```
with open(name,"wb") as f:
    file.write(bytearray(data))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I have python 2.7. At first bytesarray didnt work properly, it gave an error "byte must be in range(0, 256)". It is image compression project. Then I relized that some pixels count  greater than 255, then I splitted it into 255 bit chunks. Now work properly 9.9KB it's size. Thank you very much one more time